# Is there a way to draw a simple line or a dot on a canvas using Typescript and Vue Javascript?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am fairly new to VueJS and Typescript. I can draw a simple line with Vanilla Javascript but am looking for a simple way I can draw a circle or line or dot on a VueJS page when the page loads it should be drawn. I found libraries but they have a sketchpad for drawing but what I want is to draw those when a page loads by getting the canvas ID which is on the page. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: What you can do with Vanilla JS, it can be done exactly the same way in VueJS (no matter if you are using TS or not). Just one thing to remember is that the DOM only can be accessed in the `mounted` hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to vue's [template ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) and [lifecycle hook](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html)

Here is a simple example of drawing a line. of course you can also use other libraries (for example [fcanvas](https://github.com/tachibana-shin/fcanvas-next), [pixil.js](https://pixijs.com/) ) as you mentioned by the way:

```js
<template>
  <canvas ref="canvasRef" />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue"

const canvasRef = ref<HTMLCanvasElement>()
onMounted(() => {
  const ctx = canvasRef.value.getContext('2d')
      
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0)
  ctx.lineTo(100, 100)
  ctx.stroke()
})
</script>
```

Demo:

```js
// </script><script type="module">

import { createApp, ref, onMounted } from "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js"

createApp({
  setup() {
    const canvasRef = ref()
    
    onMounted(() => {
      const ctx = canvasRef.value.getContext('2d')
      
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.moveTo(0, 0)
      ctx.lineTo(100, 100)
      ctx.stroke()
    })
    
    return { canvasRef }
  }
})
.mount("#app")
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <canvas ref="canvasRef"></canvas>
</div>
```